# Is there a for loop in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
+---+-----+
| A | Inc |
+---+-----+
| A | Exc |
+---+-----+
| B | Exc |
+---+-----+
| B | Exc |
+---+-----+
```

This is the table I have, I have created a column of unique values in the first column (A,B)

Now if the rows with A have even one Include I want the add a column next to the Unique value column that says include. If there are no Includes it should be exclude. So it should look like this -

```
+---+-----+
| A | Inc |
+---+-----+
| B | Exc |
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,E1,B:B,"Inc"),"Inc","Exc")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I was struggling with VLOOKUP. Really appreciate your answer!

Comment: @excel_noob please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done! I have marked it as correct.